# Powershell - how i read Elements from a XML File

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this XML Dokument

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>ps read XML File</title>
<description>Some Text</description>
<item>
<title>Element One</title>
<description>Some Text to Element ONE</description>
<guid>http://dlbmodigital.microsoft.com/webcasts/wmv/23976_Dnl_L.wmv</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>Element Two</title>
<description>Some Text to Element TWO</description>
<guid>http://dlbmodigital.microsoft.com/webcasts/wmv/23977_Dnl_L.wmv</guid>
</item>
<item>
<title>Element Three</title>
<description>Some Text to Element Three</description>
<guid>http://dlbmodigital.microsoft.com/webcasts/wmv/23978_Dnl_L.wmv</guid>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I like to catch the value from the element "guid". But i don't know how to.

With this code

```
"[xml]$xmldata = Get-Content -path C:\tmp\ps\test-ps.xml
$xmldata.rss.channel.item"
```

i see the three "Item" Elements. But i have no Idea how i can catch the value (Hyperlink) from the Element "guid".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all guid-elements, then you could use xpath like this:

```
$xmldata.SelectNodes('//guid') | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"

http://dlbmodigital.microsoft.com/webcasts/wmv/23976_Dnl_L.wmv
http://dlbmodigital.microsoft.com/webcasts/wmv/23977_Dnl_L.wmv
http://dlbmodigital.microsoft.com/webcasts/wmv/23978_Dnl_L.wmv
```

Comment: Thank you for the Hint with xpath. I have to read how it works. 

My Target is, to find all Hyperlinks (Element guid) and download it.
With VB i Count the numbers of guid elements and then download with a For Loop (int_i to Count).

With Powershell i have to learn, how is the way to Access the guid elements.

Comment: Then this was exactly what you want (except downloading it). Add `| Foreach-object { #your download code } ` and you're done. But unless you have conditions to filter out some of the guid elements, then @mtman's dot-sourcing method is cleaner. I added this to give you a different solution which is compatible with all powershell versions.¨:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all children by simply referencing them:

```
$xmldata.rss.channel.item.guid
```

However, you don't get autocompletion for them. (This only happens coincidentally on 'item' as that is also a function.)

Comment: FYI that only works for V3 and higher as V3 added the member enumeration feature that allows you to "dot" a property on objects in a collection i.e. item is a collection.  In V2 you have to do this: `$xmldata.rss.channel.item | Foreach {$_.guid}`.